# 3D Skybox in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

Using the VR framework A-Frame, is there a way to have a 3D Skybox?

Either by having a 3D image, two images (one for each eye) or having two separate skyboxes (also one for each eye). Is there a built in technique for doing this or does anyone know of a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stereoscopic 3D, you can use [stereo component](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component) which lets you set one for each eye. It may need to be updated though, not sure.

Comment: Thank you, I did find this but I was wondering if there was a way to do this build into the framework. It looks like this is the answer :)